# What is the address from which /bin/ls program execution starts?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ls, bin

I need to know what's the address from which `/bin/ls` program execution starts (after dynamic linker fix the environment, what address gets the control?) I need it in hexadecimal (*0xNNN...*) or decimal format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be platform dependent. For a recent system, that should actually be randomized.